# Question related to Ellenberg Transylvanian lottery

Tags: combinatorics

On page 255 of "How Not to Be Wrong: The Power of Mathematical Thinking" Ellenberg, there is mention of a lottery game called the Transylvanian Lottery. Also shown in this video: https://youtu.be/kZTKuMBJP7Y?t=1661

From the set 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 - choose 3 numbers. Which gives 35 (7 choose 3) possible lottery tickets with numbers like 147, 245... etc.

And if a player of this lottery gets 2 numbers out of the three on their ticket to match - it is referred to as a 'deuce'. Now there is a table showing the odds of getting 0 thru 7 deuces if the player buys 7 random tickets.

Here are the numbers from that table:

```
5.3% chance of no deuces
19.3% chance of exactly one deuce
30.3% chance of two deuces
26.3% chance of three deuces
13.7% chance of four deuces
4.3% chance of five deuces
0.7% chance of six deuces
0.1% chance of all seven tickets being deuces.
```

My question is how are these percentages from this table calculated?

To me, it seems like if the called numbers in the lottery are 1, 4 and 7 - then there are 12 out of the 35 tickets that would be considered deuces.

So I was assuming that there are a total of 35!/28! ways of picking 7 tickets from 35 tickets. And to get the number of 'no deuces' it would be 23!/16!. Which I think would mean the percentage comes to be (23!/16!)/(35!/28!) or 3.65%. So I don't seem to get the 5.3% shown in the table. What am I getting wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $C(7,3) = 35$ different tickets, and for a given drawing, $C(3,2) \cdot C(4,1) = 12$ of them will be deuces, so the probability of a given ticket being a deuce is $\frac{12}{35} \approx 0.3429$.

Then, for 7 randomly chosen tickets and assuming numbers may be repeated, the probabilities follow a binomial distribution.

$$P(X = 0) = C(7,0)(\frac{12}{35})^0(1 - \frac{12}{35})^{7-0} \approx 0.0529$$
$$P(X = 1) = C(7,1)(\frac{12}{35})^1(1 - \frac{12}{35})^{7-1} \approx 0.1933$$
$$P(X = 2) = C(7,2)(\frac{12}{35})^2(1 - \frac{12}{35})^{7-2} \approx 0.3025$$
$$P(X = 3) = C(7,3)(\frac{12}{35})^3(1 - \frac{12}{35})^{7-3} \approx 0.2631$$
$$P(X = 4) = C(7,4)(\frac{12}{35})^4(1 - \frac{12}{35})^{7-4} \approx 0.1372$$
$$P(X = 5) = C(7,5)(\frac{12}{35})^5(1 - \frac{12}{35})^{7-5} \approx 0.0430$$
$$P(X = 6) = C(7,6)(\frac{12}{35})^6(1 - \frac{12}{35})^{7-6} \approx 0.0075$$
$$P(X = 7) = C(7,7)(\frac{12}{35})^7(1 - \frac{12}{35})^{7-7} \approx 0.0006$$

Your 3.65% assumes that no repeats are allowed, which means the number of deuces follows a hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: Thanks very much for the layout of your answer. It makes the process clearer. Can you explain how you came to using C(3, 2) * C(4, 1) to find the 12 deuces? I worked to the 12 by directly looking at the set of 35 tickets.

Comment: A deuce must share 2 of the 3 winning numbers plus a third non-winning number, of which there are 4 remaining. So that works out to "Choose 2 out of the 3 winners then choose 1 out of the 4 non-winners", or C(3,2)C(4,1)".